# Custom Meta Sort

Tags: django, python-3.x

This is my meta model info (Django 2).

```
class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'mydb'
    ordering = ['in_stock', '-type', 'sale_price', 'name']
```

I was wondering if I can evaluate the `in_stock` attribute dynamically.

For example:
If `in_stock=0`, then `in_stock=50`, else `in_stock=1`. My model should sort per the result of my conditional.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I think you can use a custom models.Manager and override get_queryset(), where you can fetch rows and sort them in python or use Manager.raw() to perform sorting on the database side.

Comment: Yep, definitely seems the route I need to go. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset